# Dispatch in pure JS code using React with Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a React app with Redux and Redux Toolkit. Until now I only used redux-related code in React components using `useDispatch` and `useSelector`.

Now I want to update the Redux store from a pure JavaScript module. The actual module saves user data (notes, rewards for example) into an IndexedDB. I would like to update my redux store as well from this module. However, as it is not a React component I can not use `useDispatch`.

I have created a `slice` like this:

```
const initialState = {
    rewards: []
};

export const rewardSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'reward',
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {
        setRewards: (state, action) => {
            state.rewards = action.payload.rewards;
        },
        addReward: (state, action) => {
            state.rewards = [action.payload.reward, ...state.rewards];
        },
    },
});

export const { setRewards, addReward } = rewardSlice.actions;

export default rewardSlice.reducer;
```

And what I want is the equivalent of this code without using react hooks:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
dispatch(addReward({ reward: userReward }));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `configStore.js` file or the likes where you have used `configureStore()`, you can use the assigned constant using this method and import in the file where you need to call the `dispatch()` function

for example, supposing your reducers are configured in an exported constant called `store`:

```
//Assuming the file name is configStore.js and 
//configureStore is assigned to store
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export default store = configureStore({
      reducer: persistedReducer,
      middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
          serializableCheck: {
            ignoredActions: [
              FLUSH,
              REHYDRATE,
              PAUSE,
              PERSIST,
              PURGE,
              REGISTER,
            ],
          },
        }),
    });
```

now in the file where you need to `dispatch()` to store, simply import `store`. And then destructure from it the dispatch function

```
import store from './path_to/configStore';
.
.
.
const {dispatch} = store;
dispatch(addReward({ reward: userReward }));
```

Comment: Can we do the same thing using an endpoint created by `createApi` from toolkit ? Because I can't find how to call an endpoint outside an hook.